# opencv-python addWeighted() error - Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: python, opencv, blending

I have a simple code to try out opencv image blending with `addWeighted()`
function. It shows me the error which

> Sizes of input arguments do not match

The following is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('/home/jianyepa/Downloads/gtr1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('/home/jianyepa/Downloads/r1.png')

dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,0)

cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I have check the size and channels of both image with `img.shape`, both images showing (720, 1280, 3). I have no idea why this error coming.

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: try converting the .png file to .jpg file and then perform the same.

Comment: @JeruLuke Yeah, you solved my question. Please add as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of possible problems:

1. Either the size and number of channels of the images do not match
2. Or both the images might be of different file type.

In your case, it is not the first. Both the images have the same size and same number of channels as well.

But the problem lies with the different image file types. `.png` files have another channel called the **alpha** channel which is not present in `.jpg` files. This would have caused your problem.

Comment: Root cause: different file type.